# Dsa generator verify problem

Tags: signature, dsa

I'm trying to generate a signature for DSA with the following parameters:

p=67 , q=11 , g=38 , H(m)=7 , x=6
(Is it correct to choose g=38?)

I cannot choose a random k (0>k>q) that will give me r , s that 'add up' when calculating w, u1, u2, and verifying.

I don't know where I made a mistake I've tried every possible k between 0 and 11 and I just can't get v=r at the end of verification.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> p=67 , q=11 , g=38 , H(m)=7 , x=6 (Is it correct to choose g=38?)

That's your problem; it is not correct to choose $g=38$.

$g$ has to be in the subgroup of order $q$, that is, it has to have order $q$.  In this case, $g$ is a generator for a subgroup of order 6, that is, $g^6 = 1$.

Try again with a different $g$, for example, $g=9$.

Comment: thank you so much i got it now